# Json object parsing in android

Tags: android

i want to extract json object put into the another array,i don't know how to do it,i extracted in the earlier

**{"Hyderabad": 3, "Bangalore": 1, "Mumbai": 4}**

Comment: this is full json i got only json object from url

Comment: u want to parse this object and put values of this object in an array or u want to put this whole object in JSONArray?

Comment: i want put a[0]=hydrabad,a[1]=bangalore.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate in JSON keys, using keys() method.

Example:

```
    JSONObject example = new JSONObject();
    try {
             //Creating your json
            example.put("hyderabad", 3);
            example.put("bangalore", 1);
            example.put("mumbai", 4);


            String jsonArray[] = new String[example.length()];
            Iterator keysIterator = example.keys();
            for(int i = 0; keysIterator.hasNext(); i++)
            {
                jsonArray[i] = keysIterator.next().toString();
            }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an open source library called Gson from [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list)

Use it like this..

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
yourClass[] value = gson.fromJson(yourJsonString, yourClass[].class);
```